# Printing all values contained in a map

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a map defined like this :

```
<xsl:variable name="mapping" select="myns:loadMap()"  as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"/>
```

I would like to print in my transformation all the values contained in that map.
How can I iterate over the contents of the map?

Something like this (this does not work) :

```
<xsl:for-each select="$mapping/map:entry">
    <!-- Print here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try `<xsl:value-of select="$mapping?*"/>` if that is really an XPath 3.1 map. Your attempt with `/map:entry` suggests you expect to be dealing with a node with a child element.

Due to your comment, you might want e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="map:for-each($mapping, function($k, $v) { $k || ':' || $v })"/>`.

In XSLT 4 (https://qt4cg.org/branch/master/xslt-40/Overview-diff.html#for-each) you might be able to use `<xsl:for-each map="$mapping"><xsl:value-of select="?key, ?value" separator=" : "/></xsl:for-each>`.

Saxon 11 (PE and EE) provides that as a preview/extension: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/v4extensions/xslt-syntax-extensions/iteration-maps-arrays.html

Comment: It prints the values, but not the keys.

Comment: @Sebastien, did I understand "Printing all values contained in a map" or "all the values contained in that map" incorrectly? Anyway, the function `map:for-each($map, function($k, $v) { ... })` exists to process keys and values.

Comment: yes I should have worded this differently. Print all key-value pairs.

Comment: Your solution works fine. Altough I would have liked to be able to do this with XSLT constructs instead of having to work completely with an XPath function. But I understand the map is an XPath is part of xpath-functions so it makes sense to access it this way.

Comment: You can of course process e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="map:keys($mapping)"><!-- context item here is the current key and $mapping(.) gives the current value --></xsl:for-each>`.